# Why am I getting whitespaces in StringBuilder in Java?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I wrote a method that returns a rotated `StringBuilder` with a given key. However, although it is working fine, it's adding white spaces within the `StringBuilder`.

```
public static StringBuilder rotateCipher(String plain, int key) {
    int keyTemp = key;
    char[] rotatedChar = new char[plain.length()];
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < plain.length(); i++) {
        rotatedChar[i] = plain.charAt(key);
        key++;
        if (key == plain.length()) {
            builder.append(String.valueOf(rotatedChar));
            builder.append(plain.substring(0, keyTemp + 1));
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return builder;
}
```

```
Output: nopqrstuvwxyz            abcdefghijklmn
```

Comment: What input parameters did you use?

Comment: CaesarCipher.rotateCipher("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 13);

Comment: This is really a horribly inefficient implementation.  If you want to rotate a string, its simple  builder.append(plain.substring(key); builder.append (plain.substring(0, key).  No loops needed.  I'm not sure I understand what you're going for with that.

Comment: i wanted to make this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher

Comment: The 2nd half of your `rotatedChar` array is never populated, so those entries have the default value: 0 as an ASCII character, which is non-printable.

Comment: A ceasar cipher rotates each letter. ("cat", 1) becomes "dbu". Your current solution is trying to produce something like "tca"; i.e. you are rotating the positions of letters.

Comment: Are you implementing the `Caesar Cipher in Cryptography`?
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/caesar-cipher-in-cryptography/

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the whitespace is that the array `rotatedChar` does not have all it's elements filled. By default, a `char[]` contains only `(char)0` elements.

When you call this method with the parameters `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 13` then only the first 13 elements of `rotatedChar` get filled, then you hit the if-condition and `break` out of the loop. That means you have the remaining 13 elements left as `0`s, which is a nonprintable character, so it appears as whitespace.

It's a bit hard to suggest which part to change here because as Gabe pointed out in the comments, the solution only requires 2 calls to `substring`.

If you really want to use loops, maybe this can be an approach:

```
for (int i = 0; i < plain.length(); i++) {
    rotatedChar[i] = plain.charAt(key);
    key++;
    if (key == plain.length()) {
        //this "restarts" taking chars from the beginning of the string
        key = 0;
    }
}
return String.valueOf(rotatedChar);
```

Comment: "the solution only requires 2 calls to substring." That's the solution to a different problem. He's trying to write a caesar cipher.

Comment: @Michael no, he/she is trying to find out why there is whitespace in the output. The output itself does not seem to be wrong aside from that fact. I am merely suggesting what can be changed so that the current code does not have that problem anymore.

Comment: Yes, and the top half of your answer is fine for that. The 2nd half is needlessly confusing because you're helping them to solve a problem they're not trying to solve.

Comment: @Michael maybe, but aside from the whitespace, the output wasn't found to be incorrect so far.  So I just stopped assuming anything else from there.

Comment: They posted that they were trying to implement a caesar cipher 10 minutes ago. So yes, "found to be incorrect". Anyway, if you have no interest in improving your answer to remove the confusing part then you don't have to reply any more.